# Full width horizontal nav bar with evenly spaced items

Tags: css, navigationbar

Starting point:

[image: starting point]

End point:

[image: end point]

I'm trying to have a horizontal navigation bar that fills 100% of it's container. In the first example, you'll see all of the items aligned to the left. I'm trying to get it to fill the full  width of the container as shown in the second example. I want the spacing between all of the items to be uniform (unlike the way it's shown, I just put that together quickly to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do). I need the text to not be an image and the container it goes in is fluid not fixed.

Comment: You'll usually need to know how many items you have in your menu to pull this one off. if you have 5 items, you set each item as 20% width etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a static number of elements it's easy - http://jsfiddle.net/X56cJ/

However, if you want to have uniform spacing between the text, not the elements themselves - it becomes tricky. Again, if the number of elements doesn't change, you do it with css classes and static widths. Otherwise it'll have to be javascript

**EDIT**: Here's the JavaScript way of getting same space between elements.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Our Products</li>
    <li>FAQs</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Login</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function alignMenuItems(){
    var totEltWidth = 0;
    var menuWidth = $('ul.menu')[0].offsetWidth;
    var availableWidth = 0;
    var space = 0;

    var elts = $('.menu li');
    elts.each(function(inx, elt) {
        // reset paddding to 0 to get correct offsetwidth
        $(elt).css('padding-left', '0px');
        $(elt).css('padding-right', '0px');

        totEltWidth += elt.offsetWidth;
    });

    availableWidth = menuWidth - totEltWidth;

    space = availableWidth/(elts.length);

    elts.each(function(inx, elt) {
        $(elt).css('padding-left', (space/2) + 'px');
        $(elt).css('padding-right', (space/2) + 'px');
    });
}
```

Full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NNMYy/)

Comment: Yeah, I'll have a static number of elements, and that's what I'm shooting for is uniform spacing between the text. Any suggestions on going the Javascript route?

Comment: If you have a static number of elements, than you can use pure CSS to specify the width of each element. It'll take a bit of time to get the widths right, but it's doable. While you could use JS for this, CSS will be a bit more simple.

Answer (score 3):

Using display: table on your parent, and display: table-cell on your children will do the trick. This is not supported in <= IE7.

http://codepen.io/simply-simpy/pen/jzski

Comment: That only works if all your titles are the same size.  Add `<li><a href="#">fivesixseveneightnineten</li>` to your list and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks @bronson -- I added a width: 25% and it works with a longer link. -- http://codepen.io/simply-simpy/pen/jzski

Comment: Flex-box is probably a better solution moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many elements you'll have, you can specify a width of each element as a percent. Otherwise it won't be possible without resorting to tables or javascript.