# How to Create a Full Length Navigation Menu that has Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript

I found this script which works great until you introduce a nested menu to the equation.
[script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7652656)

How can you exclude the script from being applied to the nested menu? Is there a way to give the nested menu a class or id and exclude that from the script?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can add a class to top level menu and exclude everything that is not:
HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="top-level">About Us</li>
    <li class="top-level">Our Products</li>
    <li class="top-level">FAQs</li>
    <li class="top-level">Contact</li>
    <li class="top-level">Login</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function alignMenuItems(){
    var totEltWidth = 0;
    var menuWidth = $('ul.menu')[0].offsetWidth;
    var availableWidth = 0;
    var space = 0;

    var elts = $('.menu li.top-level'); //<-
    elts.each(function(inx, elt) {
        // reset paddding to 0 to get correct offsetwidth
        $(elt).css('padding-left', '0px');
        $(elt).css('padding-right', '0px');

        totEltWidth += elt.offsetWidth;
    });

    availableWidth = menuWidth - totEltWidth;

    space = availableWidth/(elts.length);

    elts.each(function(inx, elt) {
        $(elt).css('padding-left', (space/2) + 'px');
        $(elt).css('padding-right', (space/2) + 'px');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks llia. Unfortunately that didn't work. Basically the code will work unless you introduce a nested list like below.
    `<ul class="menu">
        <li>About Us
         <ul>
                <li>Sub Page 1</li>
                <li>Sub Page 1</li>
                <li>Sub Page 1</li>
                <li>Sub Page 1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Our Products</li>
        <li>FAQs</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Login</li>
    </ul>`

Comment: I'm not sure how to get code to format correctly in a comment.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want main menu with dropdown submenus?